# My bar is not centered at all, how can I solve this problem?

Tags: html, css

I'm new here, so this is my first question. Might be a little bit stupid, but I cannot solve this problem. I created a nav bar, but it's not centered at all:

So, as you can see, where it says "galeria", clearly it'sn not at the center of the navbar. This is my code and the css for this navbar. Thank you in advance! :D

```
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a class="link" href="/">concerts</a></li>

        <li><a class="link" href="/about/">discografia</a></li>

        <li><a class="link" href="/work/">galeria</a></li>

        <li><a class="link" href="/clients/">botiga</a></li>

        <li><a class="link" href="/contact/">contacte</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And this is my css style sheet for the navbar:

```
.nav{
list-style:none;
margin:10px;
padding:150px;
text-align:center;}
.nav li{
display:inline-block;}
.nav a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #b8d2db;
color: #fff;
width: 150px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px;
font-size: 30px;
transition: 0.4s;
font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;}
.link:hover {
color: #fcff90;}
```

Comment: margin auto is sometimes useful for those moments. Maybe try it on the `li`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is centered it just doesn't look like it because the words are variable in length and you have nothing visually identifying boundaries.

To demonstrate:

```css
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #b8d2db;
  color: #fff;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
}

.link:hover {
  color: #fcff90;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a class="link" href="/">concerts</a></li>

  <li><a class="link" href="/about/">discografia</a></li>

  <li><a class="link" href="/work/">galeria</a></li>

  <li><a class="link" href="/clients/">botiga</a></li>

  <li><a class="link" href="/contact/">contacte</a></li>
</ul>
```

One way around this is to remove the explicit `width` property you set on the `<a>`

```css
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #b8d2db;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
}

.link:hover {
  color: #fcff90;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a class="link" href="/">concerts</a></li>

  <li><a class="link" href="/about/">discografia</a></li>

  <li><a class="link" href="/work/">galeria</a></li>

  <li><a class="link" href="/clients/">botiga</a></li>

  <li><a class="link" href="/contact/">contacte</a></li>
</ul>
```